# How to read the deleted data from text area in kendo UI angular

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, kendo-ui

i am using kendo UI for angular ,I have to read the deleted content and I should remove that exact content at other text area in the same component .I am using angular-13.
how to achieve this .

I didn't get any idea, please share you thoughts on this.

Comment: please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated and what is not working in your code!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what the exact setup is, but is sounds like you would need some custom logic to compare the incoming value and the old one to determine the deleted part, and update the value of the other textarea accordingly, e.g.:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohyebt-caebgr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,tsconfig.json,src%2Fstyles.css